# Two Identical Monitors, One Connected to USB-C Hub Outputs Blurry Image

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have two identical HP 24f monitors connected to my XPS 15 7590. The one to my left is connected directly to the HDMI port on my laptop, and the one on my right is connected via a USB-C J5Create hub. The resolution is 1920 by 1080p at 60 Hz for both of them, but the one connected to the USB-C hub outputs a very blurry image.

I have checked the display settings and scaling for both monitors, they both are shown to be at the exact same resolution (full hd) and the same scaling (100%). I have also updated all my drivers for the hub and the monitors.

When I connect the HDMI cable for the monitor on my right directly to my laptop, the quality is clear, and when I connect the HDMI cable for the monitor on my left to the USB-C hub, the resolution becomes very blurry. Hence, the problem seems to lie with the USB-C hub. The funny thing is that it's connected to an HDMI port which is supposed to be able to output up to 4K 60 hz.

Is there anything I can do to solve this? This is my first experience with a USB-C hub so is this just par for the course? Could it be an overheating problem?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a problem with the output color format being set to use YCbCr 4:2:2 (output using chroma subsampling intended for TVs, an interesting subject you can read more about here https://www.projectorcentral.com/chroma-subsampling-explained.htm).
Ensure that it is using RGB for the output color. That laptop can come equipped with an NVIDIA discrete GPU. If so, you may find the setting in the Nvidia control panel:

1. Right click the desktop and select "NVIDIA Control Panel"
2. Under Display click "Change Resolution"
3. There should be an "Output Color Format" option. Ensure this is set to RGB. If both displays show up here, you can check both by clicking on their respective icons.

If you don't have discrete NVIDIA graphics, check the Intel Graphics settings:

1. Right click the desktop and select "Intel Graphics Settings"
2. Click on the Video icon
3. Under Color Enhancement, Input Range, click "Full Range"

Comment: Thanks for your response! I checked my NVIDIA panel but I don't have a display tab so I went to intel, and changed the settings but it turns out Intel Command Center cannot even detect the monitor connected to my hub. Not sure how to proceed from here but I think this is related to the issue you mentioned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Got exactly the same issue, but with another monitor.
Using a DELL U2412M and it was always looking very blurry when connected to the USB-C Hub (Aukey ModeL: CB-78). When connecting it to the HDMI-Output of my Nvidia Geforce GTX however, it looked fine.

So what I did and what helped me was creating a custom resolution in the NVIDIA Control Panel and setting the "Timing" from "Automatic" to "CVT - Reduced Blanking" - and finally the monitor had a sharp and crisp output again.

Hope that helps. In case somebody else stumbles upon this, I've attached a screenshot with the correspondent settings (unfortunately only in German language, but I think it should help nevertheless).

Good luck,
Christian

[NVIDIA Control Panel Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it5zq.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the advance display settings (Right mouse click on the pulpit, then Display settings - choose the Monitor and scroll down to the Advance Display Settings) and set the Refresh rate to 59.951 Hz or other value close to 60 Hertz. It works for me.